# Is there a way to store, then reset a variable after each line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

So I have an xml file I am trying to write a quick script in node to edit, for future ease.

Every line looks like the following

```
<field name='Bank 2 Acc Type' xname='bank_2_acc_type'  locx='264' locy='407.5' width='24.75' esign='' />
<field name='Bank 2 Ch Sav' xname='bank_2_ch_sav'  locx='339.75' locy='408.25' width='25.5' esign='' />
<field name='Bank 2 Acc Num' xname='bank_2_acc_num'  locx='471' locy='408.25' width='100.5' esign='' />
```

What I want to do is take the xname, append a string like "myString" before it, then assign that attribute to esign. Example below

```
<field name='Bank 2 Acc Type' xname='bank_2_acc_type'  locx='264' locy='407.5' width='24.75' esign='myStringbank_2_acc_type' />
<field name='Bank 2 Ch Sav' xname='bank_2_ch_sav'  locx='339.75' locy='408.25' width='25.5' esign='myStringbank_2_ch_sav' />
<field name='Bank 2 Acc Num' xname='bank_2_acc_num'  locx='471' locy='408.25' width='100.5' esign='myStringbank_2_acc_num' />
```

So far I have tried to use the line-reader library to read line by line, but this doesn't return the data the way I needed it

```
const lineReader = require('line-reader');

lineReader.eachLine('./Application.txt', function(line) {
    console.log(line);
    if (line.includes('esign=\'\'')) {

        var line2 = line.toString()
        console.log(line)
        var pFrom = line2.IndexOf("xname='") + "xname='".Length;
        var pTo = line2.LastIndexOf("' ");
        
        var result = line2.Substring(pFrom, pTo - pFrom);

        console.log(result)

        return false; // stop reading
    }
});
```

This is what I have rewritten to read, I just need help editing the xml now.

```
var fs = require('fs');

function readWriteSync() {
    var data = fs.readFileSync('Application.xml', 'utf-8');
  
    var newValue = data.replace(/^\./gim, 'myString');
  
    fs.writeFileSync('ApplicationSync.xml', newValue, 'utf-8');
  
    console.log('readFileSync complete');
  }
  
  readWriteAsync();
  readWriteSync();
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:python]? Please don't tag spam.

Comment: FYI standard JavaScript properties and methods are `camelCase`, not `TitleCase`. Trying changing `IndexOf` to `indexOf`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Go checkout [xml2json on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2json).
You can convert it to json, manipulate it on the way and parse it back to xml.

```js
var parser = require('xml2json');
 
var xml = "<foo attr=\"value\">bar</foo>";
console.log("input -> %s", xml)
 
// xml to json
var json = parser.toJson(xml);
console.log("to json -> %s", json);
// maybe parse json
var myObj = JSON.parse(json)

// json to xml
var xml = parser.toXml(json);
// obj to xml
var xmlObj = parser.toXml(JSON.stringify(myObj))
console.log("back to xml -> %s", xml)
```

Comment: I actually tried converting it to json, but that isnt my issue, my issue is actually editing the content...

Comment: Then form a javascript specific questions on how to etl data. You can use a .map function and change one value in a property, by spreading it on a new obj, with the old obj.